# Unable to Filter

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to write an SQL code in my MS Access database whereby the filter on Entity_name is not working properly

```
Function FilterResults()

Dim strCriteria As String
strCriteria = ""

If Nz(Me.cboEntitynameFilter) <> "" Then
    strEntityNameFilter = "Entity_Name = '" & Me.cboEntitynameFilter & "'"
Else
    strEntityNameFilter = "Entity_Name = '*'"
End If

If Nz(Me.cboAssignmentFilter) <> "" Then
    strAssignmentFilter = " AND " & "Assignment = '" & Me.cboAssignmentFilter & "'" '& " AND "
End If

If Nz(Me.cboFYFilter) <> "" Then
    strFYFilter = " AND " & "Financial_Year = '" & Me.cboFYFilter & "'"
End If


    strCriteria = Nz(strEntityNameFilter, "*") & Nz(strAssignmentFilter, "*") & Nz(strFYFilter, "*")
'    End If


    If strCriteria = ("Entity_Name = '*'") Then
        Me.Filter = ""
        Me.FilterOn = False
    Else
        If strCriteria <> "" Then
            Me.Filter = strCriteria
            Me.FilterOn = True
        End If
    End If
```

End Function

The strCriteria returned is 
**Entity_Name = '*' AND Assignment = 'MFI'**

The filter doesn't work and the Entity_Name is all blank.  What am I doing wrong.

I am using this in MS-Access and building query in VBA

Comment: if `Me.cboentitynamefilter` emtpy than what would you like to have? ignore this filter or what, what you would like to acheive with` *`

Comment: i want to have all items in the Entity_Name to come out as a result of the query

Comment: Why do you mean with "all blank"? Do you see any existing records in the result? What are `strEntityNameFilter`, `strAssignmentFilter` and `strFYFilter`? These look like String variables but we can't see the declaration. String variables can't be NULL, so there is probably no need to use the `Nz` function. How are your comboboxes set up (bound column, column widths)? How does the filter look like when you created it in the datasheet of the recordsource of the form?

Comment: @wolfgang kais, as mentioned earlier there are records having some data in Entity Name but no record is returned by use of the *.  The issue lies in the usage of the * charachter.  It seems to be syntactically wrong.

Comment: If it was syntactically wrong, you would receive a syntax error. And no, you did not mention that no record is returned when using the asterisk, you said that in the result, that field is "all blank". You in fact mentioned only a very few things and you deny answering questions. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I would do like this

```
Dim strCriteria AS string

strCriteria = "1 = 1"

If Len(Nz(Me.cboEntitynameFilter, "")) > 0 Then
    strCriteria = strCriteria & " and [Entity_Name] = """ & Me.cboEntitynameFilter & """"
End If


If Len(Nz(Me.cboAssignmentFilter, "")) > 0 Then
    strCriteria = strCriteria & " and [Assignment] = """ & Me.cboAssignmentFilter & """"
End If

 If Len(Nz(Me.cboFYFilter, "")) > 0 Then
    strCriteria = strCriteria & " and [Financial_Year] = """ & Me.cboFYFilter & """"
End If

Me.Filter = strCriteria
Me.FilterOn = True
```

if any of the combobox or textbox didn't select than it will igonre those field.